# Laravel - How to sort array objects by timestamp value of different keys?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have this array of objects from a Laravel merged collection, accessed like this, `$collection->values()->all()`, which returns the following:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Teacher",
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 18:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "Student"
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 15:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "Course",
    "data": {
       "title: "PHP",
       "created_at": "2017-05-11 16:00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to sort the order by the `created_at` field, so it looks like this:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Teacher",
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 18:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "Course",
    "data": {
       "title: "PHP",
       "created_at": "2017-05-11 16:00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "Student"
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 15:00:00"
  }
]
```

The issue is that `created_at` is in two locations, sometimes it's under `created_at` and other times it's under `data.created_at`.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @mimo's answer does exactly what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the `sortByDesc`function:

```
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc(function ($element) {
    return $element->data ? $element->data->created_at : $element->created_at;
});
```

Comment: Switch to `sortByDesc` since the author wants to sort the date in descending order.